# Limit of integral $\int^{1/\sqrt{n}}_0 f(x) ne^{-nx} dx \to f(0)$ when $n \to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

For a continuous function $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$, I want to show that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int^{1/\sqrt{n}}_0 f(x)ne^{-nx} dx = f(0)$$

I'd considered that $$ne^{-\sqrt{n}}\int^{1/\sqrt{n}}_0 f(x) dx \leq \int^{1/\sqrt{n}}_0 f(x)ne^{-nx} dx \leq n\int^{1/\sqrt{n}}_0 f(x)dx$$ but I am not sure of how to proceed (even if this is in the right direction) to show that the limit of the integral is indeed $f(0)$.

Comment: Hint (just a thought): Substitute $z=e^{-nx}$, $dz=-ne^{-nx}dx$. Then your integral becomes $\int_{\exp(-\sqrt{n})}^1f(-(\log z)/n)dz$.

Comment: I'm afraid your inequalities provide too broad boundaries. But you can try simply $\int^{1/(2\sqrt{n})}_0 f(x)ne^{-nx} dx<\int^{1/\sqrt{n}}_0 f(x)ne^{-nx} dx<\int^{2/\sqrt{n}}_0 f(x)ne^{-nx} dx$.
Making a change of the variable $t=nx$
$$\int^{\sqrt{n}/2}_0 f(t/n)e^{-t} dt>m\int^{\sqrt{n}/2}_0 e^{-t} dt=m(1-e^{-\sqrt n/2})$$
where $m$ - is the minimum of $f(x)$ on the interval $[0;\frac{1}{2\sqrt n}]$. The same story is with the maximum $M$ on the interval $[0;\frac{2}{\sqrt n}]$.
You will get $\,m(1-e^{\sqrt n/2})<\int^{1/\sqrt{n}}_0 f(x)ne^{-nx} dx<M(1-e^{-2\sqrt n})$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show the statement of your problem by direct epsilon-type arguments.
Let $I_n=\int^{1/\sqrt{n}}ne^{-nx}\,dx=-e^{-nx}|^{1/\sqrt{n}}_0$. Clearly $0<I_n<1$ and $I_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}1$.

Now, by continuity of $f$, for any given $\varepsilon>0$ choose $N$ large enough so that

1. $|f(x)-f(0)|<\varepsilon/2 $ whenever $|x|<1/\sqrt{N}$
2. For $n\geq N$, $|I_n-1|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2(|f(0)|+ 1)}$.

Then, for $n\geq N$
$$\begin{align}
\left|\int^{1/\sqrt{n}}_0f(x)ne^{-nx}\,dx-f(0)\right|&\leq\int^{1/\sqrt{n}}_0|f(x)-f(0)|ne^{-nx}\,dx+|f(0)|\big|I_n-1\big|\\
&<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}I_n+\frac{\varepsilon}{2} \\
&<\varepsilon
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $x=\frac t{\sqrt n}$ so that the integral becomes $\int_0^1f(t/\sqrt n)\sqrt ne^{-\sqrt n t}\, dt=:I_n.$  Note that $f(0)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^1 f(0)\sqrt ne^{-\sqrt nt}\,dt$.

$\left |I_n-f(0)\right|=|\int_0^1(f(t/\sqrt n)-f(0))\sqrt ne^{-\sqrt n t}\, dt|\le\int_0^1|f(t/\sqrt n)-f(0)|\sqrt ne^{-\sqrt n t}\,dt\tag 1$

Fix any $\epsilon>0$. By uniform continuity of $f$ on $[0,1]$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for all $x,y\in [0,1] (|x-y|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon).$

Choose $y=0$ and $N$ so large that $1/\sqrt N<\delta$ (this ensures that $t/\sqrt N<\delta$ for every $t\in [0,1]$). The following holds for all $n>N$ and for all $t\in [0,1]$:

$$|(f(t/\sqrt n)-f(0)|<\epsilon\tag 2$$

So $(1)$ and $(2)$ give:
$$|I_n-f(0)|<\epsilon\int_0^1\sqrt ne^{-\sqrt nt}\,dt=\epsilon (1-e^{-\sqrt n})<\epsilon \text{   $\quad\forall n>N$}.$$

It follows that $\lim I_n=f(0)$.